# strange behavior when compile multi controllers project

Tags: iphone

I have some codes as below

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewMoreSettingController : UIViewController <  UITableViewDelegate,     UITableViewDataSource >
{}



@end




#import "ViewMoreSettingController.h"


@implementation ViewMoreSettingController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

// "MoreController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ViewMoreSettingController;


@interface MoreController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{


ViewMoreSettingController *vViewMoreSettingController;
}


@property (retain,nonatomic) ViewMoreSettingController *vViewMoreSettingController;

@end
```

//------------------------------"MoreController.m"

```
#import "MoreController.h"

#import "ViewMoreSettingController.h"


@implementation MoreController

@synthesize vViewMoreSettingController;

-(void)doSomething
{


        ViewMoreSettingController * temController ;
        temController=[[ViewMoreSettingController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewMoreSetting" bundle:nil];//a: if remove this line it will compile successfully

        [self.navigationController  pushViewController:vViewMoreSettingController animated:YES];


        [temController release];






   }
```

it will report

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewMoreSettingController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MoreController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

if I remove line a: it will compile successfully.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently were in the same situation. Simple solution is to remove those files from project by only **Delete Reference** and again add those file into project as **add existing files** will resolve the issue.